# Excel File with ODBC connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, odbc, database-connection

I have an excel file which has an ODBC connection to SQL server. It works fine on my computer because I have ODBC connection set up on mine.
But When I send the file to other people they can not connect coz they have no ODBC set up on their machine.

My question is, Is there a way to embed the connection in the excel file itself? So they don't need to setup ODBC.

Thanks in advance.
T

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a ODBC file DSN instead of a registry created DSN...

You can then ship the file DSN (something.dsn) along with your Excel spreadsheet.

As long as Excel is configured to look in the location the file DSN is placed - all should be OK...

Comment: How can you configure excel to look in a specified location for the .dsn file?

Answer (score -1):

I'd use Andy Khan's JExcel to read and manipulate the Excel file rather than JDBC and the ODBC driver.  No installation needed, but you will have a JAR dependency.

Comment: Ok what you mean is there always will be dependency? Thanks anyway.